# How to incorporate a SQL query that has LISTAGG oracle SQL function in an SSIS package?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, ssis, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to incorporate an Oracle SQL query that uses the function LISTAGG into an SSIS package. Here is the sample query I have in my SSIS package. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

I have tried using the attunity driver oracle source which gives me an error on the column/line that uses the LISTAGG function.  I have also tried using plain old oledb source which gives a very generic error message. Here is a sample query.

```
select oosi.order_key,  
       listagg(oosi.ship_instr_code, '_') WITHIN GROUP (order by oosi.order_other_ship_instrs_pos) as scode, 
       listagg(si.SHIP_INSTR_DESC, '_') WITHIN GROUP (order by oosi.order_other_ship_instrs_pos) as sdesc
from ODS_MANAGER.ORDER_OTHER_SHIP_INSTRS oosi
LEFT JOIN ODS_MANAGER.SHIP_INSTRUCTIONS si
    ON oosi.SHIP_INSTR_CODE = si.SHIP_INSTRUCTIONS_ID
where oosi.order_key = 'PIPE*TF911799'
group by oosi.order_key
```

Comment: *What* error? If you get an error that says there's no such function, it's not a driver or SSIS issue.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of oracle is the DB you are running the query against on? Listagg Function was not introduced until 11gR2.

If you are on that or above, then would need more information from the errors you are seeing.